# Making sure length of matrix row is all the same (python3)

Tags: python, list, matrix, maxlength

so I have this python 3 code to input a matrix:

```
matrix = []
lop=True
while lop:
    line = input()
    if not line:
        lop=False
    if matrix != []:
        if len(line.split()) != len(matrix[-1]):
            print("Not same length")
            menu()
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)
```

However,if I enter

```
1 2 3
4 5 6 7
8 9 0 1 2
```

my code will let it pass,but you can notice that row 2 and 3 are not same length as row 1; how to prevent that? the row have to be same length as row 1,else it has to return an error message like 'line don't have the same length. I'm not quite sure of how to do that. Maybe:

```
for row in matrix:
    if len(row) == matrix[1]
        pass
    else:
       print('not same length')
```

But it doesn't work.

Thanks

Comment: Your indenting was off. I will edit your question, and then try that code :)

Comment: Ok im waiting :) thank you

Comment: There you go, try the code now :) *and you can accept my answer if it helped you  :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want match the first row length, Try this way,

Use `len(matrix[0])`

```
for row in matrix:
    if len(row) == len(matrix[0]):
        pass
    else:
       print('not same lenght')
```

Comment: Why use `max(matrix)`? It's not finding the longest row, and you don't need the longest row anyway. `max` requires extra iteration over the matrix that will turn this operation O(n^2) instead of O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Use the builtin `len()` function and a `break` statement.

```
matrix = []
lop =True
while lop:
    line = input('Enter your line: ')
    if not line:
        lop=False
    if matrix != []:
        if len(line.split()) != len(matrix[-1]):
            print("Not same length")
            break
    values = line.split()
    row = [int(value) for value in values]
    matrix.append(row)
```

This runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python3 matrix.py
Enter your line: 1 2 3
Enter your line: 4 5 6
Enter your line: 7 8 9 0
Not same length
bash-3.2$
```

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work,it returns ' if len(line.split()) != len(matrice[-1].split()):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I got the same question but from matrix took from text file? here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532548/make-sure-matrix-row-took-from-text-file-are-same-lengthpython3

Comment: Actually,I tried it correctly, and it always says 'Not same length' even if the length is the same? thanks

Comment: How did you try it? Please tell me what input you used

Comment: Your indenting was off. I will edit your question, and then try that code :)

Comment: I tried it again with edited code,still same problem :( See edited question with the code I used

Comment: Seriously? That makes no sense. Which version of python 3 are you using?

Comment: python 3.3,check the edit of my question; I used that exact same code and it always says not same length

Comment: This works perfectly for me. That is weird. Make sure your indenting is correct, and could upload a screen video to YouTube or something else of it working? I will try to do the same...

Comment: I could send you the my module code in somewhere private or something? cause this function is in a big loop of a module...

Comment: Sure, check my profile to see my email, send me an email there :)

Answer (score 0):

```
len(set(map(len,matrix))) == 1
```

Explanation:

`map(len,matrix)` yields the lengths of all the rows of the matrix

`set(...)` gives all unique / different lengths of the rows that exist.

- If all rows have the same length, this will be a set with 1 single element.
- Otherwise, it will have 2 or more.

Finally, `len(...) == 1` returns whether what we obtained above contains 1 single element i.e. whether all rows have the same length.