# Make sure matrix row took from text file are same length(python3)

Tags: python, matrix, row, text-files

so I have this code to input a matrix from a text file:

```
            import os
            path = input('enter file path')
            there = os.path.exists(path)
            if there == False:
                print('Invalid path')
                menu()
            matrix = open(path).read()
            matrix = [item.split() for item in matrix.split('\n')]
            menu_matrix(matrix)
        except(ValueError,TypeError):
            print('Invalid character in text file')
```

My question is how to prevent to let pass a matrix that has different row length?For example a text file containing:

```
1 2 3
4 3 2 2
1 2 4 7 7
```

Should print something like 'row doesnt have the same length in the text file' and not let it pass.Im not quite sure of how to do that.

Thanks

Comment: [You just asked this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532218/making-sure-length-of-matrix-row-is-all-the-same-python3) You even accepted an answer 12 minutes ago. You can't just keep asking minor variations on the same question after 12 minutes of work.

Comment: The same technique from the previous answers works just as well here; compare the row lengths against each other and reject the array if you find a mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through the array, calling `len(array[index])` on each sub array, and then checking if it is equal to the length of the first line.

Comment: what do you mean? thanks